# Does local cohomology commute with pullback?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, sheaf-cohomology, local-cohomology

Let $Y$ be a topological spaces and $Z \subset Y$ be locally closed, i.e. $Z=V \cap U^c$ for $U,V \subset Y$ open.

For any abelian sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $Y$ let $\Gamma_Z(Y,\mathcal{F}):=\ker(\Gamma(V,\mathcal{F}) \rightarrow \Gamma(V-Z,\mathcal{F}))$ be the sections of $\mathcal{F}$ with support in $Z$. 
Denoting by $\mathfrak{Ab}(Y)$ the category of abelian sheaves on $Y$, we have the functor $\underline{\Gamma_Z}:\mathfrak{Ab}(Y) \rightarrow  \mathfrak{Ab}(Y)$, such that for $\mathcal{F} \in \mathfrak{Ab}(Y)$ and $U\subset Y$ open, we have $\underline{\Gamma_Z}(\mathcal{F})(U)=\Gamma_{Z \cap U}(U,\mathcal{F}_{|U})$.

Let $\phi:(X,\mathcal{O}_X) \rightarrow (Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ be a flat morphism of locally noetherian locally ringed spaces, which induces the pullback $\phi^*:\mathfrak{QCoh}(Y) \rightarrow \mathfrak{QCoh}(X)$, where $\mathfrak{QCoh}(X)$ resp. $\mathfrak{QCoh}(Y)$ is the category of quasi-coherent sheaves on $X$ resp. $Y$. In this case we also have that $\underline{\Gamma_Z}:\mathfrak{QCoh}(Y) \rightarrow  \mathfrak{QCoh}(Y)$.

Do we then have a commutative diagram

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathfrak{QCoh}(Y) @>\underline{\Gamma_Z}>> \mathfrak{QCoh}(Y)\\
@V \phi^* V V @VV \phi^* V\\
\mathfrak{QCoh}(X) @>>\underline{\Gamma_{\phi^{-1}(Z)}}> \mathfrak{QCoh}(X)
\end{CD}

?

Comment: Is there a counter example if $\phi$ is not flat?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for a flat morphism $\phi:(X,\mathcal{O}_X) \rightarrow (Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ of quasi-compact and quasi-separated schemes one has an exact sequence
$$
0 \longrightarrow \underline{\Gamma_Z} \mathcal{F} \longrightarrow \mathcal{F}
\longrightarrow j_*j^*\mathcal{F}
$$
Where $j \colon X \setminus Z \to X$ denote the canonical embedding of the open complement.
Applying $\phi^*$, one gets$$
0 \longrightarrow \phi^*\underline{\Gamma_Z} \mathcal{F} \longrightarrow \phi^*\mathcal{F}
\longrightarrow \phi^*j_*j^*\mathcal{F}
$$
Let  $j' \colon Y \setminus Z' \to y$ denote the corresponding canonical embedding with $Z' := \phi^{-1}(Z)$. We have the isomorphism
$$
\phi^*j_*j^*\mathcal{F} \cong j'_*j'^*\phi^* \mathcal{F}
$$
Whence, as $\underline{\Gamma_Z'}\phi^* \mathcal{F}$ is the kernel of the map $$
\phi^*\mathcal{F} \longrightarrow j'_*j'^*\phi^* \mathcal{F}
$$
you obtain the desired identification
$$
\phi^*\underline{\Gamma_Z} \mathcal{F} \cong \underline{\Gamma_Z'}\phi^* \mathcal{F}.
$$

Comment: Just wondering, the isomorphism  $\phi^*j_*j^*\mathcal{F}\cong j'_*j'^*\phi^*\mathcal{F}$ comes from flat base change, or? Does this isomorphisim also exists for the adic analytification $\phi: X^{ad} \rightarrow X$?

Comment: It's flat base change plus pseudo-functoriality (transitivity) of $(-)_*$. You need some sort of base change for your $\phi$, to repeat the argument.